# Javascript how to build json but change property with variable value

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
var date = record.get('Date'),
    day = date.getDate(),
    month = date.getMonth(),
    year = date.getFullYear();

var formattedDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

datePicker.selectedDates = {
    formattedDate: formattedDate
};
```

The result of `selectedDates` right now is: `formattedDate: '2014-7-27'`

> And I need the result to be `'2014-7-27' : '2014-7-27'`

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no syntax to do:

```
var key = "foo", val = "bar";
var obj = {
  [key]: val // syntax error
}
```

You can do this:

```
var key = "foo", val = "bar";
var obj = {};
obj[key] = val;
```

---

You can consider writing a function to delegate the boilerplating. I'm not sure what API would be best, maybe this:

```
var obj = build_object(key, val, key2, val2, ...);
```

---

ES6 gives us enhanced object literals: http://maximilianhoffmann.com/posts/object-based-javascript-in-es6 , it's still not quite what you need.

```
var a = "a", b = "b";
var obj = { a, b, func() {
  return "foo"
} } // { a: "a", b: "b", "func": function () { .. } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use square bracket syntax to add dynamic key properties to the object.

```
datePicker.selectedDates = {}
datePicker.selectedDates[formattedDate] = formattedDate;
```